# TailwindCSS in Angular: @tailwind vs @import

Tags: angular, sass, tailwind-css

i´m using Angular 13.1 (With SASS) + TailwindCss 3.0.7 for a project and found a strange behaviour.

In my `styles.scss` I imported the Tailwind styles with the `@tailwind` directive as stated on the official docs, but then when I display a component on a lazy-loaded module the styles weren´t being applied, which i fixed by importing tailwind again on each component own stylesheet.

If I change the `@tailwind` for `@import 'tailwindcss/...'` on the `styles.scss` then everything works as expected.

Can someone explain me the difference between `@tailwind` and the `@import` to understand what´s happening? I´m a newbie on CSS preprocessors...

**Working as expected**

```
@import 'tailwind/base';
@import 'tailwind/components';
@import 'tailwind/utilities';

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

h6 {
    @apply text-xl;
}

fa-icon {
    @apply p-1;
}
```

**Not working**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

h6 {
    @apply text-xl;
}

fa-icon {
    @apply p-1;
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
    require("@tailwindcss/typography"),
    require("daisyui")
  ],
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      "bumblebee",
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@import 'tailwind/base';` is in fact a small file which then does `@tailwind base;` for you. The reason it exists is that you can mix imports with `@tailwind`: imports have to all be at the top/first so you cannot have `@tailwind` and an `@import` later on.

So this is wrong:

```css
@tailwind base;
@import "./custom-base-styles.css";

@tailwind components;
@import "./custom-components.css";

@tailwind utilities;
@import "./custom-utilities.css";
```

But this works:

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "./custom-base-styles.css";

@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "./custom-components.css";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "./custom-utilities.css";
```

This is explained in [documentation here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports).

Answer (score 0):

im just doing a new project and stumbled upon this pretty randomly. It works for me and i noticed a difference in your config.content[]: while yours says `html,js`, mine says `html,ts`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

maybe its due to the file being imported in app-routing.module.**ts**:

```
loadChildren: () => import('./cv-generator/cv-generator.module').then(m => m.CvGeneratorModule) }
```